# Is it somehow possible to edit hyperlinks from or in a pdf file faster than with Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, links

I have a PDF file with several hundreds of hyperlinks (all pointing inside the file) and would like to change the destination pages faster and easier than with the built in tool contained in Adobe Acrobat. Is there a free solution for maybe exporting the Links into a text file, change them and import them back into the PDF? Or maybe a tool that shows all links in a list format, where they can be easily changed. Something like a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug-in named Aeralist, which might be helpful.

Another approach would be, if the targets of the links change because of editing the document, to use Named Destinations. There are some document editing softwares which do insert the destination markers (Framemaker comes to my mind, but I think Word is able to do that too). If you have such a development environment, the links will always go to the right place, no matter where they are in the document.